# Renaming, resizing, and moving image files in python

Tags: python, ubuntu, directory, resize, renaming

I am trying to create a program that will resize any image in a directory to 299x299. Then, I want to rename that image and convert it to a jpeg, so that all of the images will be named 0.jpg, 1.jpg, 2.jpg, etc. I also want to move the converted files to their own directory.

I have already solved the resizing portion of it. However, when I added the code for renaming, i.e. (index = 0, new_image.save)file_name, str(index), + ".jpg", and index += 1), the resizing portion no longer works. Does anyone have any suggestions?

This is what I have so far:

```
#!usr/bin/python

from PIL import Image
import os, sys

directory = sys.argv[1]
for file_name in os.listdir(directory):
        print ("Converting %s" % file_name + "...")
        image = Image.open(os.path.join(directory, file_name))

        size = 299, 299
        image.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)

        w, h = image.size

        new_image = Image.new('RGBA', size, (255, 255, 255, 255))
        new_image.paste(image, ((299 - w) / 2, (299 - h) / 2))

        index = 0

        new_image_file_name = os.path.join(directory, file_name)
        new_image.save(file_name, str(index) + ".jpg")

        index += 1

print ("Conversion process complete.")
```

Comment: Nice. But... what is your question?

Comment: I want to know if anyone has a better suggestions as to how I could achieve my intended results :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.save):

> **`Image.save(fp, format=None, **params)`**
>
> Saves this image under the given
>   filename. If no format is specified, the format to use is determined
>   from the filename extension, if possible.

The correct syntax for `image.save` is:

```
new_image.save(file_name, 'JPG')
```

---

To move a file, you can use [`shutil.move`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.move):

```
import shutil
shutil.move(file_name, 'full/path/to/dst/') # the second argument can be a directory
```

Comment: thanks! but my main question was how to rename files in sequential order and then move them to another directory.